# Can't install MS VS 2008 on a computer with MS VS 2010 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 installed on my Windows 7. And now I need also MS Visual Studio 2008. I tried to install MS Visual Studio C# Express Edition from official site and looked like installation was successfull but I can't find where it has been installed and also I can't run any my project (*.sln) that has been built at MS VS 2008 earlier.

Comment: Have you tried "open with"?

Comment: @soandos Yes, I have but can't find what I need, just **Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0** folder and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Visual Studio 2010 will convert and open Visual Studio 2008 solutions technically you don't need to have 2008. But if you have to have for some reason such as sharing between users on a source control system, it's recommended that you install the oldest version of Visual Studio first (in your case 2008) and move up to the newest version. As you install each version, it's also recommended that you run any service packs and/or fixes before installing the next version in line.

As an aside, generally when opening a 2008 solution in 2010 for the first time you will be presented with a dialog letting you know that the prior project is set to run on a older runtime and will ask if you would like to upgrade. Upgrading projects is generally not a breaking change like it was when you moved from .net 1.1 to a .net 2.0 project and in the end will give you a newer environment to work in along with newer framework options to work with.

So, uninstall everything. Clean the machine of all registry errors and then install from oldest to newest.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanx @Chris. OMG it will get a lot lot lot of my time... why so difficult? Anyway thank you for the answer it looks helpfull.

Comment: To be honest, if you are the only user of the solution, I would just go ahead and upgrade the solution and keep using 2010 as the editor. If you need to have compatibility for others, you can also have two solutions in the project, one for 2008 and one for 2010. Uninstalling and re-installing does take too much time for not much return.

Comment: So I'm now uninstalling 2010)) Seems like this is just the one way I can go through right now.

Comment: Good luck, and remember to clean up the registry. That will have a lot to do with further success with this.